# How to Create a Directory Structure from Database for treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, treeview

I am saving relative path of files in my DB as string.
I want to create a treeview from this input.
There can be multiple folders for a file path.
Please help in how to do this functionality.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't really a question; more of a how-to. You'll get better results if you tell us What have you tried. And what has failed. Otherwise, the question will likely be closed as not a real question/vague. Welcome to SO and have a read on the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit generic and vague but if I guess right your issue is how to parse the paths from the db and create the proper hierarchy of treenodes to reflect folder nesting, right?

have a look here: [Dynamic Binding Of Hierarchy Data Structure To Treeview Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HierarchyTree.aspx)

you can start with that then ask some more specific questions if something still does not work.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. In the link the example is using the depth of the folders. In my case the whole relative path is saved into the database.